# Circular crown with UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I'am trying draw a circular crown with UIBezierPath. I can draw two circle with two diferent  radius:

```
let bezierCrown = UIBezierPath()
bezierCrown.addArc(withCenter: center,
                       radius: raidus1,
                   startAngle: 0,
                     endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2,
                    clockwise: true)
bezierCrown.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x+distancia2, y: center.y))
bezierCrown.addArc(withCenter: center,
                       radius: raidus2,
                   startAngle: 0,
                     endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2,
                    clockwise: true)
```

But when I fill:

```
UIColor.green.setFill()
bezierCrown.fill()
```

Everything is filled: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76LZv.png).
I want only the crown to be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the fillRule to evenOdd

```
let center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400)
        let raidus1:CGFloat = 100
        let raidus2:CGFloat = 80
        
        let bezierCrown = UIBezierPath()
        bezierCrown.addArc(withCenter: center,
                           radius: raidus1,
                           startAngle: 0,
                           endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2,
                           clockwise: true)
        bezierCrown.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x+raidus2, y: center.y))
        bezierCrown.addArc(withCenter: center,
                           radius: raidus2,
                           startAngle: 0,
                           endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2,
                           clockwise: true)
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = bezierCrown.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

[image]

Comment: Or when a second UIBezierPath is placed on top, `bezierCrown.append(secondBezier)` and `bezierCrown.usesEvenOddFillRule = true`